# If div hidden do this

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide the body scrollbar on click, however I got 2 buttons... so I think I need to know if the body is visible or not.

The current state is that when I toggle back the body scrollbar disapears.

Im bad at explaining so here is a Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/agq8rb47/

I'm trying to avoid getting two scrollbars on the toggled divs, Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ca9Lghp3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yy").click(function() {
    $("#why").slideToggle();
    $("body").css({
      "position": "sticky",
      "overflow": "hidden"
    });
    $("#tts").css("display", "none");
    if ($("#why").is(":hidden") && $("#tts").is(":hidden")) {
      $("body").css({
        "position": "static",
        "overflow": "auto"
      });
    }
  });
  $("#tt").click(function() {
    $("#tts").slideToggle();
    $("body").css({
      "position": "sticky",
      "overflow": "hidden"
    });
    $("#why").css("display", "none");
    if ($("#why").is(":hidden") && $("#tts").is(":hidden")) {
      $("body").css({
        "position": "static",
        "overflow": "auto"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: auto;
}

#barbar {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(79, 79, 90, 0.92);
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
}

#why {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  bottom: 10%;
}

#tts {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="barbar">
  <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" id="yy"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-list fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" id="tt"></i>
</div>
<p>
  ad
</p>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>
  ad
</p>

<div id="why">
</div>
<div id="tts">
</div>
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please, try to become better at explaining things, especially when looking for help.

Comment: Hmm.. you see in my snippet that I at first got scrollbar on body. When i click on one of the icons the body scrollbar disapears(which I want(dont want 2scrollbars)). However when I click on my icon again the body scrollbar is gone

Comment: " I'm trying to avoid getting two scrollbars on the toggled divs "

Comment: to avoid getting 2 scrollbars, change overflow:scroll to overflow:auto;  Aside from that I don't understand what you mean by knowing if the body is visible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/ugy3rL0d/

the problem is that the toggle doesn't make the element hidden immediately  its delayed

so you need  to  check first if the element is hidden (we will show div now)
`then { hide body scroll }else{ show body div }`
**after that** toggle the div element

Comment: Legend, Thanks for your answer just what I was missing!